# Как писать Qt-код в MSVS 2015

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio

Пишу проект в MSVS 2015, коллега сейчас закончил свою часть, но он писал на Qt 5.6.0. Сам я с Qt не работал никогда, но по общим обзорам понял, что можно как-то подружить Qt с VS. Можете, пожалуйста, подробно описать, как мне подключить Qt к своей студии? Предполагаю, что в итоге можно будет .cpp и .hpp файлы с исходным кодом с использованием Qt-фишек вставлять в мой проект и собирать стандартным студийным образом.

Comment: Устанавливаете нужную версию кьюта онлайн установщиком, там выбираете кит под вашу версию компилятора студии.

Comment: Вообще я не вижу смысла фрейморк цеплять к студии, ведь креатор лучше интегрирован с фрейморком, та же самая философия, да и не видел я такого в студии чего нет в креаторе.

Comment: Не слушайте, QtCreator-у ещё расти и расти до студии, а в студии вполне комфортно работать с Qt после установки соответствующих плагинов, даже QtDesigner и справка интегрируются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая штука как Visual Studio Add-in https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2 . Это плагин для Visual Studio который упростит разработку с использованием qt фреймворка в Visual Studio. В нем есть возможность импортировать pro-file - файл проекта Qt Creator, в котором скорее всего работал Ваш коллега. Так же данный плагин добавляет разные шаблоны, которые упростят работу с Qt. Но, как и советовали выше, по моему мнению, лучше пытаться перебраться на Qt Creator. Он кросс-платформенный, из коробки предоставляет возможность использовать jom вместо nmake, что даст прирост скорости компиляции и кучу других преимуществ.